# How to prevent an extension from being disabled or removed?

Tags: configuration, windows

I am trying to use [Block Site](https://add0n.com/block-site.html) extension to block access to some URLs in TOR browser in Windows 7. I want to prevent disabling or removing the extension in TOR browser. I found the following recommendation in Block Site FAQs.

> How can I prevent this extension from being removed or disabled from the Firefox browser?
>
> Create a `policies.json` file with the following content. This file sits
>   into a directory called `distribution` within the Firefox installation
>   directory. You can use it to control how users have access to the
>   browser features. For more info visit
>   [github.com/mozilla/policy-templates](http://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates)
>
> ```
> {   "policies": {
>     "Extensions": {
>       "Locked":  ["{54e2eb33-18eb-46ad-a4e4-1329c29f6e17}"]
>     }   } }
> ```

I tried, but creating `policies.json` had no effect: Block Site extension still could be removed or disabled. I tried the following more simple commands in `policies.json`, still no effect:

```
{
 "policies": {
   "BlockAboutAddons": true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The option that you are using would work in normal Firefox. However Tor Browser ignores these options because it is considered to be bad practice to add other extensions to the browser and will always overwrite them during an update.

[Should I install a new add-on or extension in Tor Browser, like AdBlock Plus or uBlock Origin?](https://support.torproject.org/#faq-3)

> It's strongly discouraged to install new add-ons in Tor Browser,
>   because they can compromise your privacy and security.
>
> Installing new add-ons may affect Tor Browser in unforeseen ways and
>   potentially make your Tor Browser fingerprint unique. If your copy of
>   Tor Browser has a unique fingerprint, your browsing activities can be
>   deanonymized and tracked even though you are using Tor Browser.
>
> Basically, each browser's settings and features create what is called
>   a "browser fingerprint". Most browsers inadvertently create a unique
>   fingerprint for each user which can be tracked across the internet.
>   Tor Browser is specifically engineered to have a nearly identical
>   (we're not perfect!) fingerprint across it's users. This means each
>   Tor Browser user looks like every other Tor Browser user, making it
>   difficult to track any individual user.
>
> There's also a good chance a new add-on will increase the attack
>   surface of Tor Browser. This may allow sensitive data to be leaked or
>   allow an attacker to infect Tor Browser. The add-on itself could even
>   be maliciously designed to spy on you.
>
> Tor Browser already comes installed with two add-ons — HTTPS
>   Everywhere and NoScript — and adding anything else could deanonymize
>   you.
>
> Want to learn more about browser fingerprinting? Here's an [article](https://blog.torproject.org/browser-fingerprinting-introduction-and-challenges-ahead) on
>   The Tor Blog all about it!